# Button image is not working properly

Tags: css, yii, yii-events, cbuttoncolumn

I recently added a image to the edit button in `YII`.I do the following,

```
'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
        'header' => 'Edit',
        'template' => '{Edit}',
        'buttons' => array(
            'Edit' =>array(
            'label' => 'Edit',
            'imageUrl'=>Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/images/Actions-document-edit.ico',
           ));
```

and css for the button goes like this,

```
td.button-column a img {
    max-height:25px;
    max-width:25px;
    }
```

And the actual size of the image **Actions-document-edit.ico** is **25*25.**
I have a situation here that, i have an **25*25** image in **Google Chrome** and **2*2** image in **mozilla firefox**. Help me to achieve the proper formatting of the image in both the browsers.

[image: Google Chrome]
[image: Mozilla Firefox]

And suggest also the pagenation problem.

Comment: Are you using this image only in a specific CGridView in a webpage or on the entire CGridView of the Website?

Comment: I have only one CGridView.

Comment: Ok.Im talking about how often youll use CGridView because you can tweak the design on the framework directly so that specifying images every time you make one(CGridView) wouldnt be necessary.

Comment: @Vainglory07 Sorry i cant get you. If you are expecting more from me please inform !!

Comment: :) hmmm..how did you make the pagination to become like that?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of .ico try to use .JPEG or .png or .gif image

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please review your answer twice, before giving an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Pagenation problem was solved

```
.pager ul.yiiPager li.page:after{display: inline-block !important}
```

But still am getting image problem... Help please...